# Devise not working with Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-engines

I took the following steps:

> rails new routing_test

- in Gemfile I added devise
- rails devise g user
  invoke  active_record

  ```
  create    db/migrate/20130731191051_devise_create_users.rb
  create    app/models/user.rb
  invoke    rspec
  create      spec/models/user_spec.rb
  invoke      factory_girl
  create        spec/factories/users.rb
  insert    app/models/user.rb
  route  devise_for :users
  ```

and then, with a simple rake db:migrate, I get the following:

rake aborted!

```
Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: #<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x007feb823b6120 @paths=["/Users/krg07/Developer/core2/test/dummy/config/routes.rb", "/Users/krg07/Developer/core2/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007feb82c5e700>, #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007feb82d34440>]>
/Users/krg07/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `rescue in execute_if_updated'
/Users/krg07/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
/Users/krg07/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
```

Any idea what is going on? Thanks, really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you run `rails g devise:install` first? Also, try to lock version of devise: `gem 'devise', '~> 3.0.1'`

Comment: that was it! if you add it as an answer, i'll gladly accept it ;)

Comment: Don't really know how to paraphrase it to a proper answer… also @Dhaulagiri got it almost exactly right too, so perhaps edit his answer? Also, it would be great if could go and close the ticket on Github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had problems getting Devise to work with Rails 4 and found that most of the issues were because I was including an older version of the gem that was not updated to work with Rails 4.  Specifying the latest version of the gem helped:

```
gem 'devise', '3.0.0'
```

You may need to re-run the Devise installer after the gem has been updated.

Answer (score 1):

You are not the only one to have this problem, see the following [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10559) for more informations.

Comment: yeah ... I've been reading it. Seems that it has been fixed in the edge version, but I still get an error (different one on the edge version)