# Why am I getting this error in my routes file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Ok so I've narrowed down the error to the routes file. When I have devise_for :users even after deleting all the gems and reinstalling Devise as through the walkthrough. I get to rake db:migrate or rails s or any rails command and I get the following error.

I do not get this error if I #devise_for :users

Can someone say what's going one?

```
$ rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to updater.execute_if_updated, but up
dater is nil: #<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x3427230 @paths=["C:/Users/Shaun/Documents/Aptana
 Studio 3 Workspace/EvolvingFinal/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSe
t:0x34271d0>]>
c:3:in `rescue in execute_if_updated'
c:65535:in `execute_if_updated'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb
:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
`instance_exec'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in
`run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in
`block in run_initializers'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connect
ed_component'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_componen
t'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in
`run_initializers'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `
initialize!'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb
:30:in `method_missing'
C:/Users/Shaun/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/EvolvingFinal/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (re
quired)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependenc
ies.rb:228:in `require'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependenc
ies.rb:228:in `block in require'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependenc
ies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependenc
ies.rb:228:in `require'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `
require_environment!'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:249:in `
block in run_tasks_blocks'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `call'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:236:in `block in ex
ecute'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:231:in `execute'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:175:in `block in in
voke_with_call_chain'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with
_call_chain'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:197:in `block in in
voke_prerequisites'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:195:in `invoke_prer
equisites'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `block in in
voke_with_call_chain'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:168:in `invoke_with
_call_chain'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/task.rb:161:in `invoke'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invo
ke_task'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `bloc
k (2 levels) in top_level'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each
'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `bloc
k in top_level'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_
with_threads'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_
level'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block
 in run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `stan
dard_exception_handling'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `load'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Let me know if you want anything else posted, I like to keep my posts to what is required but here is the routes file.

```
EvolvingFinal::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'pages#home'
  resources :admins
  resources :users

  resources :books do
     resources :snippets, :only => [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  end

  post "books/:id/activate" => "books#approve", :as => "active_book"
  post "snippets/:id/activate" => "snippets#approve", :as => "active_snippet"
end
```

Comment: You've done a "bundle update" I presume?
And line 5 in environment.rb is the "initialize!" call I guess?

Comment: Yes done all that. Even tried reverting back to devise 3.0.0rc

Comment: Yes line 5 is the application initialize!

Comment: i can understand that you do not like devise, but please try to provide meaningful descriptions. also, your stacktrace looks like it's truncated.

Comment: Is it maybe related to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978479/devise-not-working-with-rails-4-0

Comment: I like devise (when it's working) but I don't know what else you want me to describe. I've given all the details of the error. I've updated the stacktrace to include the full trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Use gem 'devise', '3.0.0'
```

You may need to re-run the Devise installer after the gem has been updated.

Comment: Ok that seems to avoid the issue but now I get undefined method `secret_key=', I've been using devise 3.1.1

Comment: In your config/initializers/devise.rb file add this line:

config.secret_key = 'Your secret Key'

And use rake secret to generate your secret key.

Comment: I have done this and I still get the same error. I'm going to try and complete rollback and remove devise completely and reinstate it.